# Como posso verificar se uma tabela está vazia?

Tags: php, mysql

Pretendo verificar se uma tabela MySQL está vazia(sem nenhum registo) com PHP, como poderei fazer isso? Que tipo de consulta é que faço para me certificar disso?

Comment: Você pode usar a função não count do sql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: @Reynnan Recomendo ler sobre o site w3schools http://www.w3fools.com/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 4):

Faça um select e verifique o total de linhas:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tabela LIMIT 1");

if(empty(mysql_num_rows($select))) 
{
    echo "Tabela está vazia";
} 
else 
{          
    while($dados=mysql_fetch_array($select)) 
    {
       echo $dados['coluna'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Bia, se você fizer um `SELECT FIRST(1)NOME_CAMPO FROM tabela` obtém maior desempenho.

Comment: As funcões mysql_* estão obsoletas

Comment: @JúniorMoreira FIRST(1)?

Comment: Mysql seria 'SELECT campo FROM table LIMIT 1'

Answer (score 2):

Você vai precisar fazer um select e verificar o retorno.

Esse exemplo está em PDO.

```
$sql = DB::prepare(" SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table ");
$sql->execute();

$count = ( $sql->rowCount() < 1 ? "Vazio" : "Eita, tem alguma coisa aqui.");

echo $count;
```

Na primeira linha, onde tem DB::prepare(...); o DB é a classe de conexão (eu particularmente uso DB, isso vai de programador para programador).

Acesse o site da W3C como o amigo indicou e dê uma olhadinha em alguns tutoriais na internet, você vai achar vários.